# In T-SQL include additional column if a specific code exists in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm looking to include an additional column within a query, this would be a simple bit type column - either Yes or No. Currently, it pulls out sales within a date range and their unique SaleID, and the number of items within that sale using COUNT. What I want to do is have the next column which says if this sale included a particular item (using it's item code).

Ideally the output would be;

```
[SALE DATE] / [COUNT(Items)] / [Item #111 Included?]
29/07/2020 / 54 / No
28/07/2020 / 21 / No
28/07/2020 / 43 / Yes
27/07/2020 / 8 / No
```

I've had a look trying to use CASE but it just forces me to Group By the ItemID. Anyone got any pointers as to if this is possible and if so - what functions I need to use to achieve this. Cheers.

Comment: Nothing in your question has "Item #111", so I'm lost.  Where does this information come from?  What query are you using?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for the item code, not looking for a rework of my query as it's just a simple Select with a few joins - just a general idea of the functions that I should/could be using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want conditional aggregation.  I would put the count in:

```
select sale_date, count(*),
       sum(case when item = 111 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_111
from t
group by sale_date;
```

By changing the `sum()` to `max()` you can get a 0/1 flag:

```
select sale_date, count(*),
       max(case when item = 111 then 1 else 0 end) as flag_111
from t
group by sale_date;
```

And if you want this as `'yes'`, `'no'`, then:

```
select sale_date, count(*),
       max(case when item = 111 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as flag_yn_111
from t
group by sale_date;
```

Comment: alternatively: max( IIF(item = 111, 'Yes', 'No') )

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Didn't realise I could just add another aggregate function.